Submitting Evidence to Shopify Dispute via API
I am currently working on integrating the Shopify API to manage disputes programmatically. While I can access the dispute and its ID, I am having difficulty submitting evidence to the dispute using a backend language, specifically Python or Node.js.
It would be great if someone provide guidance on how to properly structure the API request to submit evidence to a dispute?
I tried this: write_shopify_payments_dispute_evidences and manager_orders scope is not available. Although I cant see these scopes in my app credentials scope.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
